# Nightwatch generic step definitions without duplicationg elements in pageobjects

Tags: nightwatch.js, pageobjects

I have a problem: i have a step like this:

```
this.Then(/^I click "([^"]*)" element$/, (browser, btn) => {
    var main = browser.page.main_page();

    main
      .waitForElementVisible('@' + btn, 3000)
      .assert.visible('@' + btn)
      .click('@' + btn)
});
```

I don't want to duplicate same step definition for other page object model. Is there possibility to create/build one big pageobject when i run test or make this page object contain required element without entering it multiply time in different page object model files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
this.Then(/^I click "([^"]*)" element from "([^"]*)"$/, (browser, btn, page_name) => {
    var page_obj = browser.page[page_name]();

    page_obj
      .waitForElementVisible('@' + btn, 3000)
      .assert.visible('@' + btn)
      .click('@' + btn)
});
```

Soluution 2:

create Given step definition and step like this:

```
this.Given(/^I use the "([^"]*)" page object$/, function(browser, page) {

    var p = browser.page[page] 
    if (p) {
      browser.__page = p();
    }
});

this.Then(/^I click "([^"]*)" element$/, (browser, btn) => {
    var main = browser.__page;

    main
     .waitForElementVisible('@' + btn)
     .assert.visible('@' + btn)
     .click('@' + btn)
});
```